# UnixTime saved as int, how to query as Date. Cassandra CQLSH

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, nosql, cqlsh

Im building the pipeline: sensorData - MQTT broker - Kafka - Cassandra. Payload is transferred as JSON and when saving in Cassandra, date was save as int. I can't get the readable date when query CQLSH.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sensordata.mqttsensordata (
  sensor text, 
  temperature float, 
  humidity int, 
  timestamp int, 
  battery int, 
  calibratedhumidity int, 
  datetime timestamp, 
  receiver text, 
  rssi float, 
  voltage float, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
    (sensor, temperature, humidity), 
    timestamp
 )
```

How do I get the readable timestamp when query the database like the picture below?

[Query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqzlU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time function that can operate on a UNIX timestamp is [min|max]timeuuid (`mintimeuuid()` or `maxtimeuuid()`).  You can use either of those on the timestamp column, and nest it inside the `toTimestamp()` function.

For example, if I have a table of sample times:

```
> SELECT * FROM sample_times WHERE a=1;

 a | b                               | c                                    | d
---+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------
 1 | 2021-08-08 21:42:54.131000+0000 | 96594031-f891-11eb-b7bc-e12958c8479f | 1628458974131
```

Column `d` is a `bigint` where I have stored the UNIX timestamp.  I can show that as a timestamp like this:

```
> SELECT totimestamp(mintimeuuid(d)) FROM sample_times WHERE a=1;

 system.totimestamp(system.mintimeuuid(d))
-------------------------------------------
           2021-08-08 21:42:54.131000+0000

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. Today, I found that payload UNIX time is in SECONDS, and your function require in MILISECOND, so I created UDF(user define function) to convert seconds to milisecond and put in your function:

Comment: @takeshi  Excellent!  Glad you got it to work.